# Maps in R, how to add labels to grids and points

Tags: r, maps

I'm fairly new to mapping coordinates with R, looking around and trying to merge together different tutorials, I managed to get to a point where at least the map I plot makes sense.

The code so far is as follows

```
library(oce)    
lat <- c(-77.2, -79.7, -80.7, -80.6)
long <- c(123.5, 126.1, 122.2, 121.6)
cord <- data.frame(lat, long)

par(mar=c(1.5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.5))
mapPlot(coastlineWorld, longitudelim=c(-180, 180), latitudelim=c(-90, -70),
        projection="+proj=stere +lat_0=-90", col='gray', grid=FALSE)
mapGrid(  dlongitude = 30,
          dlatitude = 5,
          col = "darkgray",
          lty = "solid",
          lwd = 0.5 * par("lwd")
        )
mapPoints(cord$long, snowpit$lat, pch=2, col="black")
```

As I said, the map makes sense and I get what I "need", in the sense that I get the right projection of Antarctica with four dots representing some places on the continent.
What I'm struggling with is a bunch of things that are needed in order to be able to just print this and used it for a report.

1. most importantly: I have no idea how to save this. I thought it was based on ggplot but when I use ggsave it seems to do... nothing.
2. I need to add labels on the side of the dots. Looking online I've seen people using text() to do so but I don't understand how to do it
3. the grid is almost readable... but it's weird: is that a way to have all the longitudes ticks around the entirety of the map and the latitude displayed on the "circles"
4. how do I change the size of the dots? again, thinking it was based on ggplot, I tried to just use size="" with an integer value but it gives me an error

Comment: consider adding the packages that you are using. Currently it is only reproducible if someone knows the packages.

Comment: Edited to add the library(oce) I'm using